# How to set multiple locations in Outlook compose form?

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api, angular7

I am currently working on an Angular outlook addin using Microsoft Graph API. I have to set and get Outlook item data in compose form. I referred the link [Get and set data items in outlook compse form](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/item-data) for doing that. In the case of location, I used

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.location.setAsync('LocationA');
```

But it will take only string. In the case of multiple locations, I cant use this property. Is there any other way to implement the setting of multiple location in Outlook compose form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [EnhancedLocation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/outlook-requirement-set-preview?context=outlook%2Fcontext#enhancedlocation) Preview API to set one or more locations that are associated with email ids. You need to use [addAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.enhancedlocation?view=office-js#addasync-locationidentifiers--options--callback-) and passing the locations to be added to the current list of locations as `locationIdentifiers`.

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.enhancedLocation
```

In read and compose mode, enhancedlocation will return an object of type EnhancedLocation, on which you can perform add/get/remove operation.

```
var locations = [
    {
        "id": "ConfRoom101@contoso.com",
        "type": Office.MailboxEnums.LocationType.Room
    }
];
Office.context.mailbox.item.enhancedLocation.addAsync(locations);
```

Also be aware that this API is provided as a preview for developers and may change based on the feedback. It is wise not use this API in a production environment.